# how to send an alert when session expires

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

i wanted to throw an alert when session expires and when you press ok button in the alert box then it will take you to login page. For this i thought to create a timer and timertask and in the run method of the later class i will check if the session exists or not. So for this i tried to create a class in jsp page but it is showing error. i can create in servlet but all my pages are in jsp and so this idea is not useful.Now i created a sessionlistner and in the session destroyed method i want to link to login page but i have a problem here too.I can not use response method in the sessiondestroyed method.Please tell me are there any other ways

Comment: Which web server do you work with?

Comment: @mauretto i use tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript like:

```
        var sessionTimeout = "<%= Session.Timeout %>";
        function DisplaySessionTimeout()
        {
            //assigning minutes left to session timeout to Label
            document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID %>").innerText = 
                                                                        sessionTimeout;
            sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;

            //if session is not less than 0
            if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
                //call the function again after 1 minute delay
                window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 60000);
            else
            {
                //show message box
                alert("Your current Session is over.");
            }
        }
```

For more details visit [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24669/JavaScript-to-Show-Session-Timeout-Counter)

Comment: thanks for this answer but please tell me what is lblSessionTime.ClientID and how will i get this and from where

Comment: This is just an example. You can use your own id.. if u visit the link, it will be helpful to u.

Comment: the link is in .net and i require in jsp

Answer (score 0):

First, you can creates totally client side solution: use `setTimout()` when page is loaded first time. Use either hard-coded or arrived from server value of timeout. When timer is triggered use `document.location = login.html` (or something like this) to arrive to login page.

This solution is "fast and dirty."

Better solution should be based on real session expiration. You can create AJAX call that tries from time to time special URL. This URL should return `true/false` that means that session is expired or not. When session is expired you should redirect the page to login screen. The problem with this solution is that the fact that you request the session state refreshes it. To solve this problem you can either perform the request to different server or (probably) remove session cookie from the polling request, so it will be performed in session different from the main session.

Comment: @alxR i do not use cookies,i use only httpsession setattribute and getattribute

Answer (score 0):

This problem is already solved by the Java EE Spec.  You should consider using web.xml configurations to handle session timeout issues.  It has specific tags for handling all of this.  Some of the tags are:

```
<login-config> ... </login-config>
```

The above tag lets you used FORM based authentication where you can specify your login HTML resource.

```
<security-constraint> ... </security-constraint>
```

The above tag lets you specify the URLs you would like to secure.  And finally the session timeout tag itself, which allows you to specify the session timeout in millis.

Once you do the above, the container would automatically take the user to the login page when he requests a secure URL.

Here is the [web.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017885) reference.

From a messaging standpoint, there are multiple ways of seeing the problem:

- The fact that system is taking the user back to the login page and forcing him to login, is indicator enough for him/her.
- You could provide a generic message on the login page itself.
- Device some tricky flag based or querystring logic to show the message on the login page.
- Came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051828/how-to-properly-message-a-session-timeout-in-jsp) in StackOverflow itself which provides a strategy you can implement in the login page itself.  Have not tried this though.

This in my mind is a trivial problem compared to the whole session timeout strategy itself.

Comment: but how can i alert when session expires as per your idea

Answer (score 0):

With Tomcat you can create a JS timer that make a simple AJAX call.
If the call return without errors the session is valid, if the call fails you can consider the session expired. On default behavior Tomcat deosn't renew sessions if you don't explicitly call it.
I had the opposit case: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513330/ajax-calls-dont-renew-session-timeout-on-tomcat-6)